# Plotly: How to create sunburst subplot using graph_objects?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

my dataframe looks something like this:

```
    user    age   gender
0    23     12     male
1    24     13     male
2    25     15     female
3    26     20     male
4    27     21     male
```

and using

```
px.sunburst(df, path=["gender", "age"])
```

gives me correct sunburst plot where gender is in middle part of pie chart and for each gender it has associated ages.

I want to do this using graph_objects instead of plotly express since I want two sunburst plots to be side by side.

from df I have above how can I use it in graph_objects. I do not understand what values to add to lables, parents, ids, etc...

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Sunburst(
        lables = df.age,
        parents = df.gender,
        domain=dict(column=0)
    )
)

fig.show()
```

I've read the documentation however I cannot understand how it works. If someone knows, please tell me how I can create sunburst plot using graph_object with df I have above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### The answer:

Just build one figure using px, and "steal" all your figure elements from there and use it in a graph_objects figure to get what you need!

---

#### The details:

If `px` does in fact give you the desired sunburst chart like this:

**Plot 1:**

[image]

**Code 1:**

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':  [23, 24, 25,    26, 27],
                   'age':   [12, 13,15, 20, 21],
                   'gender':    ['male','male', 'female','male', 'male'] })

# plotly express figure
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=["gender", "age"])
fig.show()
```

Then, to my knowledge, you'll have to restructure your data in order to use `graph_objects`. Currently, your data has the form

[image]

And `graph_objects` would require `label = ['12', '13', '15', '20', '21', 'female', 'male']`. So what now? Go through the agonizing pain of finding the correct data structure for each element? No, just build ***one*** figure using `px`, and "steal" all your figure elements from there and use it in a `graph_objects` figure:

**Code 2:**

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':  [23, 24, 25,    26, 27],
                   'age':   [12, 13,15, 20, 21],
                   'gender':    ['male','male', 'female','male', 'male'] })

# plotly express figure
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=["gender", "age"])

# plotly graph_objects figure
fig2 =go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
                labels=fig['data'][0]['labels'].tolist(),
                parents=fig['data'][0]['parents'].tolist(),
                            )
                )
fig2.show()
```

**Plot 2:**

[image]

Now, if you'd like to display som more features of your dataset in the same figure, just add `ids=fig['data'][0]['ids'].tolist()` to the mix:

**Plot 3:**

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':  [23, 24, 25,    26, 27],
                   'age':   [12, 13,15, 20, 21],
                   'gender':    ['male','male', 'female','male', 'male'] })

# plotly express figure
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=["gender", "age"])

# plotly graph_objects figure
fig2 =go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
    labels=fig['data'][0]['labels'].tolist(),
    parents=fig['data'][0]['parents'].tolist(),
    values=fig['data'][0]['values'].tolist(),
    ids=fig['data'][0]['ids'].tolist(),
    domain={'x': [0.0, 1.0], 'y': [0.0, 1.0]}
))

fig2.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and amazing explanation!

Comment: @Ambleu Happy to help!

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks! Saved me a lot of time

Comment: Thank you sir. But I have one question, how can I make it seem as whole circle, not as some part of it?

Comment: @Tugay You need to add branchvalues='total'. More info https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/#branchvalues