# How can I start a python plotly.express sunburst chart in a preselected starting position?

Tags: python, plotly, sunburst-diagram

My goal is to show users a preselection in my python sunburst chart.

As an example if I use this code:

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot
data = dict(
    character=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
    parent=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ],
    value=[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4])

fig = px.sunburst(
    data,
    names='character',
    parents='parent',
    values='value'
)
plot(fig)
```

When I run this code, the sunburst will open up with Eve as root. I wish to start with "Seth" already selected instead. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to identify and fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve that by `level` attribute in `go.Sunburst` instead of `px.sunburst`, you can set which level will be preselected. Now, if you click in the center of the preselected graph, it will take you to the original graph.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go


data = dict(
    character=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
    parent=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ],
    value=[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4])

fig = go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
    labels=data['character'],
    parents=data['parent'],
    values=data['value'],
    level = 'Seth'
))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Hamzah, thank you for taking time to answer this question. I used px because of the "path" feature (in my original problem I am using a dataframe), which is why this solution is good but not perfect. However I did not specify this in the question above AND I found a solution to this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61241172/plotly-how-to-create-sunburst-subplot-using-graph-objects so by adding this info it completes the answer, thanks!

Comment: I see, but how you can do it by px only without go objects?

Comment: I guess it is a missing feature, would be nice if someone added "level" to px.